# Why does a Decision Tree produce lines in photometric redshift predictions?

Tags: redshift

In [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350647740_Benchmarking_and_Scalability_of_Machine_Learning_Methods_for_Photometric_Redshift_Estimation) paper, the authors compare the speed and accuracy of various machine learning algorithms to produce photometric redshift estimates:

[image]

Why does the DT regressor put the estimates into bands along the `True z` axis? The only thing I can find in the paper referencing this is

> While the Decision Tree (DT) might be excluded due to the estimates being
> put into bands at set redshifts, its errors were still found to be quite
> low and it outperformed both the Linear Regression (LR) and MLP
> algorithms.

Comment: Good question. It made me have to remember how simple decision trees work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The banding is an inherent consequence of the way simple decision trees work. Each leaf in such decision trees provides a leaf-specific answer, right or wrong. In this case, each leaf in the decision tree provides a specific red shift ($z$) value.

To illustrate, I'll start with a zero-branch decision tree. Regardless of the input photometric data, this zero-branch decision tree will give the same answer. This singular answer will be $\bar z$, the average of all of the true red shift values in the training data set. (Note: The authors chose mean square error as the metric used in the decision tree. The mean is the value that minimizes the mean square error.) When plotted as a predicted $z$ versus true $z$ scatter plot when applied against the test data set, the result will be a single horizontal band at that training data set $\bar z$ value.

The above is ludicrously over the top, but it illustrates why a decision tree will show bands in a predicted versus true scatter plot. With a single branch decision tree there will be two leaves in the tree, one for the `then` branch of the single decision and another for the `else` branch, and thus two bands in the scatter plot. A two-branch decision tree will have three leaves (so three bands), and so on. One can sometimes count the number of leaves in a decision tree simply by counting the number of bands in the scatter plot.